# How to check if there are multiple of the same values in an array

Tags: c#

Say I have an array which has the following values

A B A A B C

How do I run a code which will increment the integer variables a, b, and c according to the amount of the times they occur in the array

Comment: as a hint, I'd suggest running a distinct list and use the intersect (or potentially Count()) method thereafter on one list against the other...

Answer (score 7):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var array = new string[] {"A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C" };

var counts = array
    .GroupBy(letter => letter)
    .Select(g => new { Letter = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

If you want to get the counts individually, you can put everything into a dictionary

```
var countsDictionary = array
    .GroupBy(letter => letter)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

var aCount = countsDictionary["A"];
var bCount = countsDictionary["B"];
//etc...
```

Comment: plus one dave - exactly what I would have suggested (and/or distinct with count)

Comment: what if the values aren't letters, but like words.

Comment: Why does it need to be that complicated? What's wrong with Enumerable.Count()?

Comment: Does the addition of the dictionary method explain it?

Comment: @Lukos - That loops over the list n. times - less efficient I'd suggest (depends on the array, though)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example at the bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535181%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

It basically does what you need.

```
var array = new string[] {"A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C" };
int a = array.Count(p => p == "A");
```

Comment: If you have 10 'letters' you'll have to iterate over the entire list 10 times to get the counts this way

Comment: Microseconds in reality, at least that is my assumption without anything to the contrary in the OP.